# Using Java to query Active Directory to find available CIFS shares

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap, cifs, jcifs

Here is the scenario:

I have several `CIFS` partitions which AD-based users can mount and use to access their files etc.

Now we have a requirement to expose this to users via Java-based Web application. So ideally when the users log in; he/she should be able to see which all `CIFS` partitions he has access to. This would mean that that Java application should be able to query Active Directory server via `LDAP` or such to identify which all `CIFS` partitions are available and the respective `ACLs`.

So the question is:

1. Can we use `LDAP(Java-based library)` to query AD to find out which
   users can access which `CIFS` shares?
2. Is there any other way to do so from a Java application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no builtin way to publish CIFS partitions, or their respective ACLs, to AD.  So you need to publish it yourself.  There's basically two options:

1. Publish it in AD.  This requires [extending the schema](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759633%28v=ws.10%29.aspx), i.e. creating a cIFSPartition class with two attributes, path and users.  You would then have to find a Java library that can perform LDAP queries (I see a lot of questions about [Spring LDAP](http://www.springsource.org/ldap) here).  You would probably need to make a webpage to help create and manage these cIFSPartition objects.
2. Store it on the webserver.  You have lots of options here, like a text file or database.  This way, you don't have to worry about LDAP.